# Shared object store for multiple checkouts with Google's 'repo' tool?

Tags: linux, git, repo

In my organization, we are using Google's `repo` tool to maintain a codebase spread over ~200 git repositories. Since compilation and test runs a quite slow, I usually have more than out checkout of that source tree on my Linux machine (e.g. one that's currently compiling, and another one where I prepare the next commit).

These checked-out source trees consume about 7.5GB each, with 5.5GB being the git object store (ordinarily in the `.git` folder of each repository, but `repo` redirects this to a `.repo` folder in the root of the source tree) and only 2GB for the actual working copy. So my question is: how can I (easily) make those different checkouts share their object stores so that each git object in the object store is stored only once on my hard disk?

I know that this is possible with multiple checkouts of an individual git repository, but am not sure how repo's redirection of the object store might affect these approaches. Simply replacing duplicate files by hardlinks will probably not work, since git is storing most objects in shared pack files, and those won't be identical between different checkouts even if the objects inside them are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm doing is this:

1. Run `repo init` to initialize the new repo.
2. Inside `.repo` and create two symlinks called `project-objects` and `projects` which point to the same-named directories in the existing `.repo`.
3. Then go up one level and `repo sync`.

`repo` likes this so far; if I run into any problems, I will update this answer.

Almost certainly, we want to avoid running concurrent `repo` operations in repo trees that share objects this way, because these operations could, in turn, issue concurrent operations in the same `git` repos.

If this is the way to go, the obvious next step is to put the global object store outside of any `.repo` directory in some special location, and point all of them there via symlinks.

It looks like the `--mirror` and `--reference` parameters of `repo` should achieve something similar, but I can't find any documentation on them to explain what exactly they do and `repo help init` is scant in details. It looks as if `--mirror` is supposed to pull down a local mirror of a repo (not a client checkout but a special mirror object), and which is then referenced with `--reference` parameters when checking out client repos.

The advantage of the symlinks is that I understand what they are doing without having to read undocumented Python source.

Comment: Sounds good for a basic setup, but what about data integrity? Normal user operations (e.g. `git pull`) will occasionally trigger git's garbage collection mechanism, which will eliminate objects from the object store that are unreachable from *that working copy*. If I share the object store as you propose without informing git about the sharing, won't the garbage collection potentially delete objects that are unreachable by one working copy, but could be vital to the other one (e.g. commits creating in one of the working copies but not yet pushed)?

Answer (score 0):

I have make a prototype: https://github.com/zhangchunlin/git-repo/commit/0c16efd203f0b768c103362386f9ae67730bb78f

But after test it didn't work well, when it is a big git and need to pack to a pack file, workspace 1 and workspace 2 of repo will create 2 git pack file, that is to say not share. Tested with git 1.9.1 ,2.10.1, 2.18.0, all the same result.

```
user1@server1:~/.project-objects/platform/external/sonivox.git/objects/pack$ ll
total 40648
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1     4096  7月 11 22:30 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 user1 user1     4096  7月 11 17:16 ../
-r--r--r-- 1 user1 user1   600272  7月 11 22:30 pack-1f3a4c983b7a4c0e6233201745b07f43e5c6daf4.idx
-r--r--r-- 1 user1 user1 20202460  7月 11 22:30 pack-1f3a4c983b7a4c0e6233201745b07f43e5c6daf4.pack
-r--r--r-- 1 user1 user1   600468  7月 11 17:16 pack-47b57752fd0d754b098b23654c31c8dc9be83cd0.idx
-r--r--r-- 1 user1 user1 20203424  7月 11 17:16 pack-47b57752fd0d754b098b23654c31c8dc9be83cd0.pack
```

If this can be sovled, I think it is possible workable